# Can someone explain how integration by parts was done?

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

I just would like someone to identiy u and dv.

Comment: Just as a general note, this is a great resource for integration by parts (I teach all my students integration by parts using LIATE:
http://www.math.binghamton.edu/grads/reff/m222/LIATEandTABULAR.pdf

Comment: $u=\ln{x}$ and $dv=y\, dx$.  This leads to $du=\frac{dx}{x}$ and $v=yx$.

Comment: @mathematics2x2life, that is a pretty awesome way to teach it. I learnt it as lipet!

Comment: @Luis It works just as well. I like 'P' for polynomial (I assume) because it makes it easy for the student to pick up things like $x^2$ for $u$. But it does lose the case when we let $u=1$. I always said algebra was stuff like squaring or multiplying. So that includes the '$1$' and polynomials. But I suppose that choice depends on the student, class, and teacher. But LIATE was how it was first introduced in back in around $1985$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u=\ln x, dv=dx$  The $y$ inside the integral is a constant because the integration is over $x$.  The lower limit is just that.

Answer (score 0):

$u=\ln x$

$dv=dx$.

Remember that you treat $y$ as a constant.